# fullCalendar and bootstrap theme

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I try to use the "bootstrap5" theme on the excellent [fullCalendar 6](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/themeSystem).

I followed the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/bootstrap5).

My config is :

```
const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'timeGridDay',
                locale: 'fr',
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
                },
```

The page source looks like that (this picture to show that everything is present)

[image]

[image]
But the displayed theme is the standard one :

[image]

What can be my error ?

Comment: Are you using fullcalendar 6? Did you follow all the further instructions mentioned in the documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/bootstrap5? You didn't provide details or a [mre] of your issue, so it's difficult to identify what could be wrong.

Comment: thanks Adyson for your answer. I updated the initial question

Comment: It's a little difficult to tell still, because that's not just the standard theme in your picture - you seem to have included some additional colours, at the very least. https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PoLaYYg shows what it should look like with bootstrap 5. It's easier to tell if you're using that theme, if you show us a bigger screenshot of your week view, including the day headings etc - they are distinctly different from the standard theme (as shown here: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/eYjromb)

Comment: Also, on closer inspection the documentation I think misses out a step. If you look at the provided demo on the fullCalendar website, it also includes an extra JS file, which describes itself as a fullcalendar bootstrap plugin: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/bootstrap5@6.1.10/index.global.min.js . If you include that file then you also get the blue buttons and subtly different icons: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/RwdJbNE

Comment: Thanks ADyson, you were right. I added this extra JS file and now it is OK, the bootstrap theme is applied.